# How do I set up CMake to generate header-only projects?

Tags: c++, c, build, cmake

I want to set up header-only C++ (or C) library projects, but can't find a clean way.

After some searches I've found that you can't set up a normal library using `add_library` to do this because it requires a compilable source file.
A way to do this would be to use `add_custom_target` instead, this way:

```
# Get all headers (using search instead of explicit filenames for the example)
file( GLOB_RECURSE XSD_HEADERS 
    *.hxx
)
add_custom_target( libsxsd SOURCES ${XSD_HEADERS} )
```

But that doesn't seem to work completely here as I can't see the sources in the project generated in VS2010. I don't know if it's a bug or if I'm doing it wrong or if there is a preferred way to do this.

Comment: what do you want to do with all your headers ? The only thin you can do is copying them somewhere ...

Comment: I want: 1) to have them displayed in a project generated by CMake - I've just managed to do that in several different ways just minutes ago. 2) When a project needs those headers, just make the header-only a dependency => implicitely add the include file of the header-only project. At the moment I've tried a lot of different ways to do it but failed.

By the way, I've searched for boost projects way to do it but failed.

Comment: dependencies are foudn by cmake by scanning other project headers.
If oyu want to know where the fiels live etc, the cmake way of thing is to make a FindFOO that try to find FOO headers and set up appropriate macro to the values of their location.

Comment: how about adding a source file which does nothing apart from including all the headers?

Comment: @Joel Falcou> Ok I'll look more at this but I'm a bit lost withe the FindFOO function, not sure why I can't grasp it.
@Agnel Kurian> I tried that, it allows to create the project (say project K) but there don't seem to be any way to make sure the other projects that depends on headers of K will have access to those headers. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong because I have a normal library (say A) that, like K with a fake cpp file, does use add_library AND include_directories but when I target A I get the includes in the project but not when I target K. I'm lost...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Update:** CMake will soon include a library target called INTERFACE that is ideal for header-only projects. This feature is currently in the master branch. [Reference](http://www.kdab.com/modern-cmake-with-qt-and-boost/).

Using the command `add_custom_target` as you propose works for me (VS2010). The files are neatly listed within my project but it has the drawback that you can't define any "Additional Include Directories" with a custom target. Instead, I now use the following:

```
add_library(HEADER_ONLY_TARGET STATIC test1.hpp test2.hpp)
set_target_properties(HEADER_ONLY_TARGET PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```

This sets up your header-only project as a dummy archive target. Don't worry, no actual binaries will be generated if you should try and build it (at least not in VS2010 and Xcode 4). The command `set_target_properties` is there because CMake will otherwise complain that it cannot infer the target language from .hpp files only.

Comment: This is not portable and will fail at compile time with make (error `ar: no archive members specified`).

Comment: @ComicSansMS Thanks for pointing that out! I didn't test this with make myself. Since you didn't post an answer of your own, I figure that there is no portable alternative. Someone should make a feature request to the CMake team.

Comment: The best way I could figure out so far is to add a `dummy.cpp` to the library just to keep CMake and the compilers happy. Apart from the noise of creating unnecessarily creating an intermediate static library file for the header-only libs, it works quite well.

Comment: That workaround is fine for the header-only library itself, but as soon as you try target_link_libraries(main hdr) it fails because there's no .lib

Comment: Also for the INTERFACE libraries I haven't found a way yet to add files. You can't add include dirs and link to other libs conveniently either.

Comment: Agreeably, it would be nice to have `target_link_libraries(TARGET HEADER_ONLY_TARGET)` link everything together as you propose. It's unfortunate that this approach doesn't work. You can use `include_directories(TARGET HEADER_FILES)` instead as a work-around. Here, `HEADER_FILES` is an array of the header files used to generate the `HEADER_ONLY_TARGET`.

Comment: The newly released CMake 3.0.0 supports INTERFACE libraries [see add_library documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_library.html) Unfortunately I haven't learned how to use them yet.

Comment: @ErikSjölund old post I know but INTERFACE libraries don't have source dependencies and thus the headers don't show up in an IDE.

Comment: [target_sources()](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/target_sources.html) might be helpful to get the headers to show up in an IDE.  That CMake command was introduced in CMake 3.1. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/29218394

Answer (score 11):

You can do this using the recent [Interface Library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries) feature:

```
add_library(mylib INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(mylib INTERFACE my_include_dir1 my_include_dir2)
```

This creates a library target without any source files, and adds the include directories to the [INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html#prop_tgt:INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES) property of the target. This means that any target that links to this library will get these directories as include paths (`-I`) when built.

For instance, to use the library with an executable target, just do:

```
add_executable(myexec ${MY_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(myexec mylib)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is just adding an include directory using the 
["include_directories" command for cmake.](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3ainclude_directories)

When doing this, if it is a third party tool that you don't have control over, I would also add the "SYSTEM" flag.

So you command would look like something like this:

```
include_directories(SYSTEM ${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Comment: Thats not exactly what I want: I want to see the files inside the generated solution/project.

Comment: I just started using CMake and unfortunately i am stuck with old version of CMake which does not support INTERFACE and your solution works for me. I have no IDE requirement, working on Linux, VIM.