# How to create a cmake header-only library that depends on external header files?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project with the following file structure:

```
project
 |
 |-------> lib1
 |           |----> lib1.h
 |
 |-------> lib2
 |           |----> lib2.h
 |
 |-------> main.cc
```

The two libs `lib1` and `lib2` only contain header files while `lib2.h` includes `lib1.h`, and `main.cc` includes `lib2.h`.

How do I write the cmake file for this project now? I tried to create an [interface library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries) for `lib2`, but the compiler can't find `lib1.h`. Here are the contents of my cmake files:

**CMakeLists.txt for lib2:**

```
add_library(lib2 INTERFACE)
target_sources(lib2 INTERFACE lib2.h)
target_include_directories(lib2 INTERFACE ../lib1/lib1.h)
```

**CMakeLists.txt for the whole project:**

```
add_executable(project main.cc)
target_link_libraries(project lib2)
```

What's the problem in the cmake files?

Comment: Can't you just list your headers in `add_executable` and remove all `add_library`?

Comment: One thing that seems odd in your source code and could explain the problem: `target_include_directories()` is only for directories that contain header files. So it should be `target_include_directories(lib2 INTERFACE ../lib1)`.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As stated in the comments, `target_include_directories` should be given a path to a directory, not to a file.

Moreover, if you want to create a dependency for `lib2` on `lib1`, you should do it through `target_link_libraries`: a dependency is not only about include directories, but also about compile options, definitions, target properties...

`target_sources` doesn't work with interface libraries. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29214327/6612932), You can use a custom target without commands to associate the sources to a target without impacting the build process (for msvc, QtCreator and other GUI-based tools, this makes the sources accessible through the IDE; AFAIK it's useless for other build tools).

Your cmake may look like this:

```
add_library(lib1 INTERFACE)
target_sources(lib1 INTERFACE lib1.h)

target_include_directories(lib1 INTERFACE
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib1"
)

add_library(lib2 INTERFACE)
if(MSVC)
    add_custom_target(lib2.headers SOURCES lib2.h)
endif()

target_include_directories(lib2 INTERFACE
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib2"
)

target_link_libraries(lib2 INTERFACE lib1)

add_executable(project main.cc)
target_link_libraries(project lib2)
```

Advanced tip: you can specify a different directory in `target_include_directories` for the build tree and the install tree (see [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html)):

```
target_include_directories(lib1 INTERFACE
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib1>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${YOUR_INSTALL_DIR}/lib1>
)
```

Comment: `target_sources` shouldn't be needed since target is of type "INTERFACE", and isn't compiled by itself. Passing sources directly to `add_library` even gives the following error: `add_library INTERFACE library requires no source arguments.`

Comment: BTW `target_sources` is also needed for sources to be visible in *Projects* pane of *QtCreator* IDE easily.

Comment: I'm using cmake 3.5.1 and for the line `target_link_libraries(lib2 lib1)` I get this error  
  
`INTERFACE library can only be used with the INTERFACE keyword of target_link_libraries`  
  
I guess it means `lib2` by the interface library here. I can get past this error if I add the INTERFACE keyword in the target_link_libraries command before `lib1`.  
  
`target_link_libraries(lib2 INTERFACE lib1)`

Answer (score 5):

I've used an empty `_only_for_compiling_the_lib.cpp` file as the simplest and fastest workaround, but clearly the above solution is strongly advised.

I simply wasn't aware of `INTERFACE` keyword.

Comment: I still can't understand how do other solutions work and would prefer empty cpp again

Answer (score 3):

This problem was due to full path issue of INTERFACE library files, which got fixed in cmake version  3.13.

For more info:
https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17556

This page also contains an example for better understanding.