# How to create a cmake header-only library that depends on external non-header-only target?

Tags: c++, cmake

[How to create a cmake header-only library that depends on external header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39887352/how-to-create-a-cmake-header-only-library-that-depends-on-external-header-files/39889958) is close but different.

I have a single-header library, `MyHeaderLib`. In `MyHeaderLib/MyHeader.h` I have `#include <QString>`, so anyone doing `#include "MyHeaderLib/MyHeader.h"` had better have `QString` in their path (i.e., Qt5Core to CMake, I think(?)) and it they'll need to link to Qt5Core.

What belongs in my `CMakeLists.txt` for `MyHeaderLib`? I have

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

add_library(MyHeaderLib INTERFACE)

target_include_directories(MyHeaderLib include/) 
# (^ Where include/ contains MyHeaderLib/MyHeader.h)
```

Anything I try with `target_link_libraries(MyHeaderLib` requires `INTERFACE` and if I do `target_link_libraries(MyHeaderLib INTERFACE Qt5Core)` that doesn't suffice.

Ultimately I got it to work as follows, but I don't understand what is going on:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED) # <- Can't be Qt5::Core

add_library(MyHeaderLib INTERFACE)

target_include_directories(MyHeaderLib include/) 
# (^ Where include/ contains MyHeaderLib/MyHeader.h)

target_link_libraries(MyHeaderLibrary 
INTERFACE
    Qt5::Core # <- Can't be Qt5Core
)
```

I gather the targets with `::` in them are aliases, but I'm perplexed why it needs to be exactly like this. Furthermore, I can't find `add_library(Qt5::Core ALIAS Qt5Core)` anywhere. What is going on? Why do I have to `find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)` and not `find_package(Qt5::Core REQUIRED)` and why can't `target_link_libraries` take `Qt5Core`?

Comment: Thats just how the packages have been declared: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.10/cmake-manual.html or alternatively https://blog.kitware.com/cmake-finding-qt5-the-right-way/

Comment: By that you mean CMake's built-inn Qt support magically knows that when I look for `Qt5Core` I get `Qt5::Core`? I'm a CMake n00b... If one is an alias for the other, why aren't the two names interchangeable to `find_package` and to `target_link_libraries`?

Comment: The `find_package(XYZ ...)` can be entirely different from the target you link to with `target_link_libraries`. In this case, there's a `FindQt5Core.cmake` (or maybe `Qt5CoreConfig.cmake`) which declares the `Qt5::Core` target. They could have written it to declare `Qt5Core`, but they chose to make it `Qt5::Core`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages are responsible for defining targets. The Qt maintainers chose to name the package `Qt5Core` while deciding to define the `Qt5::Core` target.

Usually the convention with CMake packages is that a package named `package-name` will define `package-name::package-name` with maybe other optional targets or subcomponents of `package-name::package-name`.

As to answer why Qt don't act like this, look inside `Qt5CoreConfig.cmake`, you'll see this line:

```
add_library(Qt5::Core SHARED IMPORTED)
```

Here you go. The file is named `Qt5CoreConfig` so it needs `find_package(Qt5Core)`, but the target is under the `Qt5` namespace as they choose to define it.

This is maybe because Qt5 Also has a general package which you can use components:

```
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)
# Here Qt5::Core kinda make sense.
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! So the issue is that packages and targets are different things and That `find_package` makes much more sense, visually at least. And it appears to work the same if you write it `find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)` which reads even more like `find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)`.

Comment: But... how does the existence of `Qt5CoreConfig.cmake` define a package named `Qt5Core`? Is it cmake magic that if I try to `find_package(Foo REQUIRED)` it looks for `FooConfig.cmake` in some path? I'd kind of expect to see an `add_package` command somewhere saying "I'm the Qt5Core package", but that's not a thing, apparently.

Comment: @Ben yes. Suit yourself in the documentation about [cmake-packages](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html) and [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html)

Comment: @Ben you can add packages using the `install(EXPORT ...` command or by writing the files manually. Well behaving CMake libraries exports their targets.